# A piece of javascript in footer.php wordpress does work on PC but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code in my footer.php on my wordpress website

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("questionnaire");
if (myForm) {
  myForm.onsubmit = function() {
var questionDiv = document.getElementById('question-div');
var busyDiv = document.getElementById('busy');
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result-div');
var resultList = document.getElementById('result-list');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxx/exec";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onload = function() {
  if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var result = response.result;
    for (var i in result) {
      var e = result[i];
      if (e) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        if (e.url) {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = e.url;
          a.textContent = e.name;
          li.appendChild(a);
        } else {
          li.textContent = e.name;
        }
        resultList.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
    busyDiv.hidden = true;
    resultDiv.hidden = false;
  }
}

var form = document.getElementById('questionnaire');
var formData = new FormData(form);
var fields = ['name','email','yob','gender','xxx','yyyy'];
var params = [];
for (var i in fields) {
  var field = fields[i];
  params.push(field + "=" + formData.get(field));
}
xhr.send(params.join('&'));

questionDiv.hidden=true;
busyDiv.hidden=false;


return false;
  };
}
</script>
```

This has allowed me to write and quote data from a google sheet

Now all this works on PC but it delivers 404 not found error on mobile site and the website itself is preset to be mobile responsive.

Can somebody help please?

Jane

Comment: Does the page itself 404? If so it's got nothing to do with the Javascript in your footer. It seems unusual that an AJAX query would behave differently on mobile or desktop as well.

Comment: You need to test this in a fiddle to know whether its this script or anything else in your web page that is causing the issue on mobile browser. Go to this fiddle link and test the code by pasting the #questionnaire form element and then checking the results: https://jsfiddle.net/h9pxkucr/

Comment: @dave: so the page is fine, then id input some data and click submit. then the page refreshes into a 404...

Comment: Do you think its a theme problem? I will look more into that. and will test on jsfiddle thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What does your form html look like? I suspect that your mobile browser is trying to submit the form via the standard - non AJAX way and therefore is directing the browser to the url in the "action" attribute of your form. Try the following to stop this default behaviour

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("questionnaire");
if (myForm) {
  myForm.onsubmit = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Hey i think you are right. the html on pc is different from html on mobile -- the html on mobile includes all the data input. adding this code stops the page on mobile going into a 404. but  once I added this code. the page on mobile just stay as is on submit....

Comment: the page is supposed to run the code and load some data from google sheet, but instead, it stays unchanged before and after clicking submit

Comment: the website is www.fintrez.com you can check via phone and then youd see...